# Make WPF application multillingual

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making my WPF application multilingual. But here i am facing one problem if I placed `Setlanguage()` methods in app.xaml its working fine. But when I am try to implement my code in main page after login its not working.

below is my code please help:

```
public MainMenuView()
{
    SetImportCatalog();
    SetLanguage();
}
#region SetLanguage
private void SetImportCatalog()
{
    try
    {
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path);
        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(WPF_Globalization.ViewModel.BaseModel.Instance.ImportCatalog);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
private void SetLanguage()
{
    try
    {
        MvvmCommand.SmartInfoServices.Service1Client client = new MvvmCommand.SmartInfoServices.Service1Client();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        var categorylist = new List<ProjectTabModel>(1);
        ds = client.getLangLayoutPrefrence("1");
        string cultureCode = string.Empty;
        categorylist = new List<ProjectTabModel>(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
        foreach (DataRow row1 in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            var values1 = row1.ItemArray;
            var category2 = new ProjectTabModel()
            {
                LanguagePrefrence = values1[2].ToString(),
            };
            categorylist.Add(category2);
            cultureCode = category2.LanguagePrefrence;
        }
        CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(cultureCode);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
        var dictionary = (from d in WPF_Globalization.ViewModel.BaseModel.Instance.ImportCatalog.ResourceDictionaryList
                          where d.Metadata.ContainsKey("Culture")
                          && d.Metadata["Culture"].ToString().Equals(cultureCode)
                          select d).FirstOrDefault();
        if (dictionary != null && dictionary.Value != null)
        {
            this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary.Value);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Are you looking for an application that allows switching of languages at runtime or an application that supports different language cultures?

Comment: @Gusdor Thanks for reply yeah i am looking for application that support different languages cultures.

Comment: Do you want a different layout for each language or are you happy just changing the text?

Comment: @Gusdor just want to change the text...:)

Comment: It doesn't have to be hard! try this sample http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30035/Simple-WPF-Localization

Comment: @Gusdor I am avoiding write code in app.xaml(private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)) because i need userid i am setting my language prefrence in database. So i want to write my getcultureinfo code in main window. Does this make sense.

Comment: You can happily bootstrap to system wherever you see fit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57486/discussion-between-vishu-minhas-and-gusdor).